# A problem on smallest $\sigma-$ algebra in Axler's Measure theory book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Could you please give me some hints on this problem please (this problem is from Measure, Integration and Real Analysis, section 2.28, Axler, 2020)

> $X$ is a set. $A$ is the set of subset of $X$ such that $A$ = {{$x$}: $x \in X$}.
>
> Prove that the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$ that contains $A$ is the set of all subset $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ is countable or $X$\ $E$ is countable (which I will call the set $B$ from now on).

My idea is to prove that $B$ is the intersection of all $\sigma-$algebra on $X$ that contains $A$. To do it, I must prove that every element of $B$ $\in$ an arbitrary $\sigma-$ algebra on X that contains $A$.

But from here, I'm stuck at how to prove a set is in a $\sigma-$ algebra.

Thank you very much for any comments or any hints.

Comment: So you want to show that $\sigma(A) = B$ (that is exactly what is asked). You may proceed as follow : 1) show that $B$ is as $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$. 2) show that each $\sigma$-algebra that contains $A$ also contains $B$.

Comment: Do you know what a $\sigma$-algebra is?

Comment: @David C: Yes, I know what it is. It would be great if you have some hints on how to solve this problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $X$ is a set. $A$ is the set of subset of $X$ such that $A$ = {{$x$}: $x \in X$}.
>
> Prove that the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$ that contains $A$ is the set of all subset $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ is countable or $X$\ $E$ is countable (which I will call the set $B$ from now on).

**Proof**: Let us write $\sigma(A)$  to indicate the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$ that contains $A$. Let $B$ be the set of all subset $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ is countable or $X \setminus E$ is countable

**Item a**. In this exercise, it is need to prove that $B$ is, in fact, a $\sigma$-algebra. It can be done by just checking the definition.

$1$. $\emptyset$ is countable, so $\emptyset \in B$.

$2$. If $E \in B$ we have two possibilities: $E$ is countable or $X$\ $E$ is countable.

$2$.a.If $E$ is countable, then $X \setminus E^c= X \setminus (X \setminus E)=E$ is countable, so $E^c\in B$.

$2$.b. If $X \setminus E$ is countable, then $ E^c = X \setminus E$ is countable, so $E^c\in B$.

So, in both cases, we have that $E^c\in B$.

$3$. Given a countable collection $\{ E_n\}_n$ such that, for all $n$, $E_n \in B$, we have that:

$3$.a If for all $n$, $E_n$ is countable, then $\bigcup_n E_n$ is countable and so, $\bigcup_n E_n \in B$.

$3$.b If there is one $n_0$ such that $X \setminus E_{n_0}$ is countable, then
$X \setminus \bigcup_n E_n= \bigcap (X\setminus E_n) \subseteq X \setminus E_{n_0}$ is countable and so, $\bigcup_n E_n \in B$.

So, in both cases, we have that $\bigcup_n E_n \in B$.

So $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Item b**. Let us now prove that $\sigma(A) \subseteq B$.
Since for each $x \in X$ , $\{x\}$ is countable, we have that $ A \subseteq B$. Since $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it follows that $$ \sigma(A) \subseteq B \tag{1}$$

**Item c**. Now let us prove that $ B \subseteq \sigma(A) $.

Let $E \in B$.

If $E$ is countable, then $E$ can be written as a countable union of single-point subsets (that is $E=\bigcup_{x \in E} \{x\}$). Since all single-point subsets are in $A$ and $\sigma(A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $E \in \sigma(A) $.

If $X \setminus E$ is countable, then, by the previous paragraph, $X \setminus E \in \sigma(A) $. Since $\sigma(A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $E \in \sigma(A) $.

So, in both cases, $E \in \sigma(A) $. So, $$ B \subseteq \sigma(A)  \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $\sigma(A) = B$.